# How to put data into request body intercepted on EnvoyFilter?

Tags: lua, istio, envoyproxy

I'm trying this, but doesn't work and doesn't show any error.

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: eva-decrypt-data
  namespace: eva
spec:
  configPatches:
    - applyTo: HTTP_FILTER
      match:
        context: ANY
        listener:
          filterChain:
            filter:
              name: "envoy.http_connection_manager"
      patch:
        operation: INSERT_BEFORE
        value:
          name: envoy.lua
          typed_config:
            "@type": "type.googleapis.com/envoy.config.filter.http.lua.v2.Lua"
            inlineCode: |
              function envoy_on_request(request_handle)
               local buffered = request_handle:body()
               buffered:setBytes("new body data")
```

Comment: What is your istio version? Are you trying to set this filter on the gateway or on a specific sidecar pod?

Comment: Hi @V.Junior, please answer Jereon question + please provide following information: which Kubernetes version are you using? Which Kubernetes solution are you using - cloud provider (which one) or bare-metal (which one)? Which [installation configuration profile](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/additional-setup/config-profiles/) did you use for Istio? You have written: "doesn't work and doesn't show any error." - how are you testing it? Please share steps / tutorial that you followed and make [your issue reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The problem was istio version, request_handle:body():setBytes("") works only above 1.10

Comment: Hi @V.Junior, could you post your comment as the answer so the solution will be visible for the community?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posted community wiki based on comment for better visibility. Feel free to expand it.

---

The issue is solved. Function `request_handle:body():setBytes("")` works only on Istio version above 1.10:

> The problem was istio version, request_handle:body():setBytes("") works only above 1.10